# Notice : session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring in

Tags: php, mvc

Cordial Saludo.

Me encuentro en el aprendizaje de PHP con MVC, he realizado un proyecto de Barberia, donde el usuario crea una cuenta, pero en el momento de realizar login, me dice que esta ignorando la sesión y me aparecen estos dos errores.

El proyecto lo tengo en un servidor real, no en el localhost de mi PC.

> Notice : session_start(): A session had already been started -
> ignoring in
> /home/devcray2/public_html/barbershop/controllers/LoginController.php
> on line 29
>
> Warning : Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at
> /home/devcray2/public_html/barbershop/controllers/LoginController.php:29)
> in
> /home/devcray2/public_html/barbershop/controllers/LoginController.php
> on line 40

He bucado la respuesta en este grupo y en el de ingles, aplicando diferentes metodos pero no logro dar con la solución. Acudo a ustedes para que me guíen por favor.

Adjunto código.

```
<?php

namespace Controllers;

use Classes\Email;
use MVC\Router;
use Model\Usuario;

class LoginController
{

    // Direcciona a la página principal
    public static function login(Router $router)
    {
        $alertas = [];

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            $auth = new Usuario($_POST);
            $alertas = $auth->validarLogin();

            if (empty($alertas)) {
                // Comprobar que exista el usuario
                $usuario = Usuario::where('email', $auth->email);

                if ($usuario) {
                    // Verificar el password
                    if ($usuario->comprobarPasswordAndVerificado($auth->password)) {
                        // Autenticar el usuario
                        session_start();

                        $_SESSION['id'] = $usuario->id;
                        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $usuario->nombre . " " . $usuario->apellido;
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $usuario->email;
                        $_SESSION['login'] = true;

                        // Redireccionamiento
                        if ($usuario->admin === "1") {
                            $_SESSION['admin'] = $usuario->admin ?? null;
                                // debuguear($usuario);
                            header('Location:./admin'); 
                        } else {
                            header('Location:./cita');
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Usuario::setAlerta('error', 'Usuario no encontrado');
                }
            }
        }
        $router->render('auth/login', [
            'alertas' => $alertas
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Este código `session_start();` no debe tener ninguna otra línea antes. Es lo primero que debe existir en tu archivo PHP, en todos donde lo vas a necesitar.

Puedes [Leer la Documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) o este [Interesante Articulo](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-use-sessions-and-session-variables-in-php--cms-31839).

Answer (score 0):

pon la función `session_start();` hasta el inicio de todo el documento, después de la etiqueta de apertura, y asegúrate que antes de la etiqueta de apertura no haya ninguna salida de texto.

además de eso agregala a la condición

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
```

para que de esa manera verifique si ya hay una inicialización de la sesión por que si ya existe una inicialización marcará un error